# Deleting files based on Substring match

Tags: linux, unix, unix-timestamp

In folder there are files eg A_17APR2012.csv . My requirement is to delete all the files except today's timestamp

I tried doing this to list all the files **not having** today's date timestamp

```
#!/bin/ksh

DATE=`date +"%d%h%Y"`
DIR=/data/rfs/
FOLDER=Test
FILE=$DIR$FOLDER

UDATE="$(echo $DATE | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')"

ls $FILE | grep -v "${UDATE}"

exit 0
```

This is listing all the files not having today's date timestamp. Now I have to delete the files which are listed .Kindly help me out how I can delete the files.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
find folder -type f -not -name '*'$(date +"%d%h%Y")'*' -delete
```

where "folder" is the directory containing files to be deleted.

Comment: This query helps a lot . Only problem I am facing is if there are no files in the folder then its deleting the folder itself.It should not delete the folder and the files are 18APR2012 format.Kindly help me out

Comment: @user680204, give this version a try and let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have some small mistakes. In the ls line it should by UPDATE not UPADTE. Also, probably the UPPDATE line should be with UPDATE and `` (backticks). After the fixes the the script  is:

```
#!/bin/ksh 

DATE=`date +"%d%h%Y"`
DIR=.
FOLDER=
FILE=$DIR$FOLDER

UPDATE=`echo $DATE | tr [a-z] [A-Z]`

ls -1 $FILE | grep -v "$UPDATE"

exit 0
```

Note that I added also "-1" to ls.

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes are :

```
UPPDATE= echo $DATE | tr [a-z] [A-Z]
```

you need to change it to :

```
UPPDATE="$(echo $DATE | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')"
```

Works perfectly

```
pearl.388> cat temp2.sh
#!/bin/ksh

DATE=`date +"%d%h%Y"`
DIR=data/
FOLDER=Test
FILE=$DIR$FOLDER

UPPDATE="$(echo $DATE | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')"

ls -1 $FILE | grep -v "^${UPPDATE}"

exit 0
pearl.389>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd want to use the find command,  it has options that will check the timestamps for you, i.e.

```
rm `find /data -ctime +1`
```

That will remove all fines in /data who's status was changed 24 or more hours ago

There are lots of ways to check the timestamps using find.

Comment: This will remove files according to modification time but in this scenario one can modify file at any moment. So this query will not give correct results